# advantage of using style.width.px instead of defining it in ngStyles or external style

Tags: html, css, angular, ng-style

Can someone tell me the advantage of using `[style.width.px]` syntax over styles defined in `ngStyles` or over `style defined in an external css file`. I don't think it makes much difference if we define it either way.

I saw somewhere that `[style.width.px]` adds dynamic styles but couldn't understand as in which scenario this would be required. Can someone expose such scenario where using `[style.width.px]` kind of property would be useful?

Comment: using the js style means it will override any other styles that are not marked !important.  I would only use it when doing something dynamically that needed a width adding manually (at the time I was going to manipulate it).  For example an image slider often wraps the images in one big div and adds a width calculated from the number of images and their widths.  Other than if I was using js to change a width dynamically, I would always use a stylesheet

Answer (score 2):

> ngStyle

Basically used when we have to provide multiple stlyes in a single object let suppose you have to change height, width and color and so on dynamically or statis than you can use ngStyle.

- ngStyle accepts object having key as css property's and value and static or dynamic values. for example

  ```
   [ngStyle]="{'font-style': styleExp,'width':'30px', 'height': dynamicHeight}"
  ```

> style.width.px

is used when you have to set width dynamically according to some conditions than you can achive this using this syntax liek this

```
[style.width.px]="width"
```

> style

external style is used basically when style is static there is no dynamic value in the style